# Azure Resource Graph query

Tags: azure, azure-resource-graph

How can I pull all properties for a service that are avaliable to query for?

I have a start but I would like to know everything I can list

```
resources

| extend type = case(

type contains 'microsoft.netapp/netappaccounts', 'NetApp Accounts',
strcat("Not Translated: ", type))

 | where isnotempty(tags)

 | where tags <> "{}"

 | project name,type,resourceGroup,subscriptionId,tags,location
```

Comment: I'm looking for the created date and created by information.

Answer (score 0):

Usually every Azure Resource Graph entity has a property called "properties" which contains a json with all kinds of metadata depending on the resource type.
You can query the json simply by calling

```
creationTime=properties.CreationTime
```

You will probably not find all the data you are looking for there. For specific auditing data like "created by" you can query the Azure Monitor audit logs.